# Page not redirecting when submitting the form

Tags: python, flask, python-3.7

I am creating a blog application. I created a registration form with post method that asks for details. In the flask route, I am trying to check if my form is validating correctly or not. To achieve this, I created an if statement and when the condition is true, I am trying to redirect to the home route. Which is not happening. I am not sure what is the problem here. But I can see the post is giving 200 status code.

I tried to print something but it does not print anything. I tried to remove the method from the html file, I tried redoing the register route My guess is the validation itself is not happening.

```py
#home route
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, title="Home")

# register route
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        print("Account creation success")
        return redirect(url_for('home'))  # function name for the route.
    return render_template('register.html', title="Register", form=form)
```

```py
# forms.py file
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from  wtforms import StringField,PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired,length, Email,EqualTo
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username= StringField('Username',validators=[
        DataRequired(),
        length(min=2, max=20)
    ])
    email= StringField('Email',validators=[
        DataRequired(), Email()
    ])
    password= PasswordField( 'Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirmPassword = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(),EqualTo(password)])
    submit= SubmitField("Sign Up")
```

```html
<!--This is layout.html which is parent for the home page-->
       <div class="col-md-8">
            {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
                {% if messages %}
                    {% for category, message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-{{category}}">
                            {{ message }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith%}
            {% block content %}{% endblock content%}
        </div>
```

```html
<!--This is register.html which will render the form -->
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <!--adds cross site request forgery token. Needed for secuity.-->
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.confirmPassword.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.confirmPassword(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>

            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted">
            <!-- url_for() uses the  name of the route function           -->
            Already Have an account? <a class="ml-2" href="{{ url_for('register') }}" >Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The expected output is the page has to redirect to the home.html but for some reason, it stays at register.html and there are no error messages. I even get 200 status code for the post operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the form it has errors:

`{'confirmPassword': ["Invalid field name '<UnboundField(PasswordField, ('Password',), {'validators': [<wtforms.validators.DataRequired object at 0x7fecdc7b6e80>]})>'."]}`

It is because you passed `password` field instance to `EqualTo` validator instead of its name as a string: `'password'`.

```
confirmPassword = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
```

Comment: It worked thank you. But how did you get those errors? What debugger should i use?

Comment: I use PyCharm debugger.

Comment: I use pycharm aswell but i did not get any error. All i can see is the success codes thee requests. did you use break point on the if statement?